# Bootstrap align icon to leftside of button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap 3 button and it's using font awesome for the icons. I am trying to Center the text on the button but have the icon aligned to the left side.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">
  <i class="fa fa-home pull-left"></i> Home
</button>
```

When I use `pull-left`, there is no padding or margin so the icon is too close to the edge (image 1).

[image]

However, when I try to add a `margin-left` or `padding-left` to the icon, its moving the text over to the right as well (should remain center).

[image]

Is there a way to not push the text over when using margins or padding on these icons?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmm please see the snippet it could solve your problem. Used `position` on new added class selector `left-icon-holder`.

```css
.left-icon-holder {
    position:relative;
}
.left-icon-holder .fa {
    position:absolute;
    line-height: 24px;
    top:50%;
    margin-top: -12px; /* Half of line height to keep left middle postion of container */
    left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" />

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block left-icon-holder">
  <i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home
</button>
```

Comment: Works for me - seems like the stock glyphicons can use pull-left as I intended but the font-awesome gave me trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You use a pseudo-element to display the icon:

```css
button::before{
 position: absolute;
 font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
 display: inline-block;
 font-style: normal;
 font-variant: normal;
 text-rendering: auto;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 font-weight: 900; 
 content: "\f015";
 left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">Home</button>
```